# Remote connect to Windows from Ubuntu

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, ssh, popen

I have a Python program that I'm running in Ubuntu on a local machine.  At some point during the program I connect to two remote machines:  one running Ubuntu and the other running Windows.  I have the IP addresses, names, and passwords to connect to these machines.  The local machine sends the remote machines a command, and the remote machines send a response.  Right now I'm just trying to get the remote machines to echo 'hello' back to the local machine.  I can remote into both of these machines on the command line from my local machine using:

```
sshpass -p password ssh -X name@ipaddress
```

where *password*, *name*, and *ipaddress* are correctly filled in for each machine.  So I know that I can remote into both of the machines just fine.  From there I can run any command as if I was on that machine locally.

However, I would like to do this from within my program while sending in a simple `echo 'hello'` instruction.  I can successfully accomplish this with the remote Ubuntu server with the following:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
cmd = ["sshpass", "-p", password, "ssh", "-X", name+"@"+ipaddress, "echo 'hello'"]
ssh = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
print ssh.stdout.readlines()
```

The *password*, *name*, and *ipaddress* are variables that are already defined by this point.  This works on the Ubuntu remote server where it returns the following list:

```
['hello\n']
```

This is good, but when I try the same on the Windows server I get an empty list:

```
[]
```

I've tried various commands and I always get an empty list.  Is there something else or different that I need to be doing when connecting to the Windows server?  Thank you in advance.

I looked at the stderr and that includes the following list:

```
['X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0\r\n', 'exec request failed on channel 0\r\n']
```

When I don't include the -X tag then I only get the second error:

```
['exec request failed on channel 0\r\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

The target machine most likely does not have a Linux like commands installed.  Install something like [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) on the Windows machine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the issue is that I can get a response from the windows server if I type in the commands in the command line by hand, but when I try to automate the process in a Python script I don't get any response.  However, I have no issues when I connect from Ubuntu to Ubuntu.